How does locals() behave when I try to modify the local scope in Python?
I've been exploring the locals() function and noticed something unexpected when trying to modify variables in the local scope. Here's what I mean:
def my_function():
    x = 10
    print("Before modifying locals:", locals())
    locals()['x'] = 20
    print("After modifying locals:", locals())
    print("Value of x:", x)

my_function()

When I run this, the output is:
Before modifying locals: {'x': 10}  
After modifying locals: {'x': 20}  
Value of x: 10  

I expected the variable x to change to 20, but it stays 10 even though the dictionary returned by locals() shows the updated value.
Why doesn't modifying locals() actually change the variables in the local scope? Is there something special about how Python handles local variables in a function?
